# How to skip a few lines of code if an element is in a list?

Tags: python

I am making a texted based game in python.  I am currently stuck on a system where you unlock a certain feature, and once you unlock that one, you have to get a certain amount of points, you can unlock the next one.  But I'm having trouble, here's my code:

```
if HS >= 100 and HS <= 199:
        print("You have enough HS points to unlock a new feature!")
        conf = input("Do you want to unlock a new feature? ")
        if conf == "yes":
            features.append("feature1")
            locked_features.remove("feature1")
            HS = HS - 100
            print("You have unlocked feature1!")
            print("Your available feature are: ", features)
            print("You now have", HS, "HS points. ")
    elif HS >= 200 and HS <= 299:
        features.append("feature2")
            locked_features.remove("feature2")
            HS = HS - 100
            print("You have unlocked feature2!")
            print("Your available feature are: ", features)
            print("You now have", HS, "HS points. ")
```

HS are the points needed to unlock a new feature.  there is a list called "features" which has all of the available features for the players.  Locked_features is the one the player cant use until they unlock them.
However, I when I unlock feature 1, and then get 100 HS points, it asks me if a want to unlock a new feature.  But when I type "yes", it just comes up with the error "Feature1 was not in Locked_features".  How do I make it skip the lines for Feature 1 if I already have unlocked it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't know if this is exactly the logic you want, but here's the basic idea...just check to see if the feature is already enabled by looking in the 'features' list:

```
if HS >= 100 and HS <= 199:
    if not "feature1" in features:
        print("You have enough HS points to unlock a new feature!")
        conf = input("Do you want to unlock a new feature? ")
        if conf == "yes":
            features.append("feature1")
            locked_features.remove("feature1")
            HS = HS - 100
            print("You have unlocked feature1!")
            print("Your available feature are: ", features)
            print("You now have", HS, "HS points. ")
if HS >= 100 and HS <= 199:
    if not "feature2" in features:
        features.append("feature2")
        locked_features.remove("feature2")
        HS = HS - 100
        print("You have unlocked feature2!")
        print("Your available feature are: ", features)
        print("You now have", HS, "HS points. ")
```

I also changed the logic so that you can get the second feature for 100 HS if you already have the first feature, and still get both if you have 200 HS.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. One can be to add another criteria to your ifs. Like this if not "feature1" in features.

For the first IF this gives you:

```
if HS >= 100 and HS <= 199 and "feature1" not in features:
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it seems to me that you have an indentation error on the elif statement. As for your question, I think that you could just check whether the feature exists in the array or not, every time.

Replace the 4th line of the code shown above, with this:

```
if(conf == "yes" and "feature1" in locked_features):
```

This way, every time the user selects "yes", **the statement will only run if the feature you are trying to remove (namely, 'feature1')** is in the locked_features array. But I think that the general flow of the program is wrong. You ask the user whether he/she wants to unlock a new feature in general and when he/she selects yes, you automatically select feature 1. I'm not sure that this is what you want. You should separately check whether the user wants to unlock a feature and then  ask input about the feature number or something. Just a little hint :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Instead of checking points, the if statements are now checking whether each feature is in `locked_features`.

```
    if HS >= 100: # I removed the cap of 199.
        print("You have enough HS points to unlock a new feature!")
        conf = input("Do you want to unlock a new feature? ")
        if conf == "yes":
            if "feature1" in locked_features: # Added this check after conf == yes
                features.append("feature1")
                locked_features.remove("feature1")
                HS = HS - 100
                print("You have unlocked feature1!")
                print("Your available feature are: ", features)
                print("You now have", HS, "HS points. ")
            elif "feature2" in locked_features: # Similarly for feature2, and so on
                features.append("feature2")
                locked_features.remove("feature2")
                HS = HS - 100
                print("You have unlocked feature2!")
                print("Your available feature are: ", features)
                print("You now have", HS, "HS points. ")
```